# Continue search in table where previous cell left found criteria

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match

Consider the following table (original array spread as follows `A1:P23`):

```
Member || Collab01 | Collab02 | Collab03 | Collab04 | Collab05 | ...      | Collab15
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AA     || Yes      | Yes      | No       | No       | No       | ...      | No
AB     || No       | No       | No       | No       | No       | ...      | No
AC     || No       | Yes      | Yes      | No       | No       | ...      | No
AD     || No       | No       | No       | No       | No       | ...      | No
AE     || No       | No       | No       | No       | No       | ...      | No
AF     || No       | No       | No       | No       | No       | ...      | No
AG     || Yes      | Yes      | No       | No       | Yes      | ...      | No
...    || ...      | ...      | ...      | ...      | ...      | ...      | ...
AV     || Yes      | Yes      | No       | Yes      | Yes      | ...      | Yes
```

Cell `B25` lists Members, choose one of them
Cell `B31` contains nested `IF`s using INDEX-MATCH statements to find according to `B25` (say AB has been chosen) and try to find the 1st `Yes` by column. Algorithm looks like this:

```
=IF(INDEX($B$2:$P$23,MATCH($B$25,$A$2:$A$23,0),MATCH("Collab01",$B$1:$P$1,0))="Yes",$B$1,IF(INDEX($B$2:$P$23,MATCH($B$25,$A$2:$A$23,0),MATCH("Collab02",$B$1:$P$1,0))="Yes",$C$1,IF(INDEX($B$2:$P$23,MATCH($B$25,$A$2:$A$23,0),MATCH("Collab03",$B$1:$P$1,0))="Yes",$D$1,IF [etc.]
```

If the algorithm finds nothing (i.e., there are only `No`s in the corresponding row), then it should display: `"Not applicable or no data submitted"`

What cell `B32` needs to do is to continue where cell `B31` left off.

What has been achieved so far:

- a formula which allows me to get the cell address of what cell `B31` found: `=IFERROR(CELL("address",INDEX(B1:P1,MATCH(B31,B1:P1,0))),"")`
- a formula that states the next column (could be helpful to start the column after where cell `B31` finished): `=INDEX(B1:P1,MATCH("Collab"&TEXT(RIGHT(B31,2)+1,"00"),$B$1:$P$1,0))`

**Question**: *without using VBA*, how to write the algorithm in cell `B32` so that it starts in the same row as `B31`, but 1 column farther and continues the analysis of to find the next `Yes`?

Comment: I feel perhaps you are approaching this problem in a more complex way than is required. From what I understand; you are trying to use formulae in cells `B31,B32...` to return the location of any `yes` values in their row. Is this correct? In that case, an array formula using `LARGE()` on the array of column numbers where you've got a `yes` might work

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Greedo. Cell `B31` does already what I want: it looks up what member has been chosen in cell `B25` (i.e., member `AC`) then only for that row, it would scan the columns until it finds the 1st `Yes` and return the header of that column. In the case of `AC` that would be `Collab02`. Cell `B31` stops there. Cell `B32` takes over and starts searching for the next `Yes`, if exists. In this case it does, it will return `Collab03` as there is a `Yes` in the crossing of `AC` and `Collab03`. Then cell `B33` would do the same as cell `B32`, but starting at `Collab04`, etc.